# Connect to Message Queues on IBM MQ from .NET/C# Code using IBM Client Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

My goal is to create an application which can send/receive or publish/subscribe messages using the IBM MQ Messaging Solution

We are trying to connect to a Queue Manager in an IBM MQ Container Application from .NET/C# using IBM's example code here: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/dotnet

We configured the env.json according to the defaults as follows:

```
{
    "MQ_ENDPOINTS": [
        {
            "HOST": "<redacted>",
            "PORT": "1414",
            "CHANNEL": "DEV.APP.SVRCONN",
            "QMGR": "QM1",
            "APP_USER": "mqm",
            "APP_PASSWORD": "<redacted>",
            "QUEUE_NAME": "DEV.QUEUE.1",
            "MODEL_QUEUE_NAME": "DEV.APP.MODEL.QUEUE",
            "DYNAMIC_QUEUE_PREFIX": "APP.REPLIES.*",
            "TOPIC_NAME": "DEV.BASE.TOPIC"
        }
    ]
}
```

After running the solution, we get the following error:

> XMSException caught: IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to  the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2540.

If Searched by code, IBM Docs at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=codes-2540-09ec-rc2540-mqrc-unknown-channel-name say: **MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME**

The Channel **DEV.APP.SVRCONN** does exist on the MQ instance.
MQ Instance is hosted as Container.

After going through a few Forum posts, documents, etc. We got the suggestion to use a system Channel such as **SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN**
In that case, it will throw error as **MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR**

At the end of the day, our goal is to create an application which can send/receive or publish/subscribe messages using the IBM MQ Messaging Solution.

Comment: You should see a 'matching' error in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG saying the channel did not exist - look for AMQ9519E. If you don't see this error there is a possibility that your hostname or port number were incorrect and you connected to another queue manager and that other queue manager does not have a channel of that name defined.

Comment: You say MQ is running in a container. Is the container on the same machine as the  .NET app? In which case the host will be`localhost`.  If the container is running in the cloud then the channel may be `CLOUD.APP.SVRCONN`, but the port is unlikely to be `1414` and in the cloud, TLS will be enabled.

Comment: @MoragHughson

No such Queue, even a system Queue.
Host Name and Port are correct, I copied from browser address bar for Web Console directly, Port is 1414 default listner.

Comment: @chughts Container on Azure AKS Cluster, Developing on local system

Comment: Deployed using https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm/tree/main/samples/AzureAKS ?

Comment: So what does the AMQERR01.LOG say? If it doesn't also mention the channel not being defined, you did not connect to the queue manager you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not connecting to the queue manager that you think you are.  i.e. There are multiple queue managers on that server/host and you are connecting to the wrong one.

Each queue manager will have its own listener running on a particular port.  i.e. 1414. But if you have multiple queue managers on the server then each one MUST have their own port #. i.e. 1414, 1415, 1416, etc.

First, you had an error with the channel name then an error with the queue manager name which definitely points to a misconfiguration by you.  I would strongly suggest that you speak with your MQAdmin about what are the correct parameters for that particular queue manager you want your application to connect to.

> SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN

Finally, no application or user should be using the SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN channel. It goes against IBM MQ Best Practices.

Comment: No intention to use SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN as a Channel, it was just an debugging step.
We are the MQAdmin, as we are hosting the MQ in Container in on AKS